# GROUP and COUNT() multiple fields in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

This is my database:

```
week, subbizname, devicetype
20141203, common, PC
20141203, unknown, PC
20141210, KRsinKD, SP
20141210, unknown, PC
20141217, Unknown, SP
20141217, Chintai, TAB
....
```

I am trying to get the number of records for each unique couple devicetype/week.
Ex:

```
array(
  20141203 => array(
     'PC'=>2,
     'TAB'=>0,
     'SP'=>0
  ),
  20141210 => array(
     'PC'=>1,
     'TAB'=>0,
     'SP'=>1
  ),
  ...
  .....
)
```

UPDATE:

I have used query:

```
$data = $this->Test->find('all', array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'OR'=>array(
                array('devicetype'=>'PC'),
                array('devicetype'=>'SP'),
                array('devicetype'=>'TAB'),
            )
        ),
        'fields'=>"devicetype,week,COUNT(devicetype) AS countDevice",
        'group'=>"week,devicetype"
    ));
```

Thing is, it returns something like this:

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'devicetype' => 'PC',
        'week' => '20141126'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'countDevice' => '34844'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'devicetype' => 'SP',
        'week' => '20141126'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'countDevice' => '32401'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'devicetype' => 'TAB',
        'week' => '20141126'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'countDevice' => '4256'
    )
),
(int) 3 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'devicetype' => 'PC',
        'week' => '20141203'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'countDevice' => '96564'
    )
),
(int) 4 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'devicetype' => 'SP',
        'week' => '20141203'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'countDevice' => '97450'
    )
),
```

But I do not manage to get the expected result.
Surely there must be a better way.
How can I fix this?

Comment: "SELECT week, devicetype, COUNT(*) AS Cnt, FROM tbl GROUP BY week, devicetype" should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your $data variable, you can do:

```
$d = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $week = $value['Test']['week'];
    if (isset($d[$week])) {
        $d[$week][$value['Test']['devicetype']] = $value[0]['countDevice'];
    } else {
        $d[$week] = array($value['Test']['devicetype'] => $value[0]['countDevice']);
    }
}

print_r($d); // $d will contain the data in your required format
```